# Scikit-learn DecisionTreeClassifier - multi-output decisions with string and float columns

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a multi-output  problem that I'm trying to solve with `DecisionTreeClassifier`.

My training set consist of set of books with different features. Based on this features,  I would like to predict two outputs for each book: category (drama, fantasy,  sci-fi) and number of pages for this book. Each book can belong only to one category.

I'm using code similar to this

```
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier() 
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

where  y_train is a Dataframe with two columns - the first one is a string column (category) and the second one is a float column (number of pages).

When running the code I'm getting the error listed bellow.

If I omit one of the columns (single output problem), everything works OK.

Based on the call stack, it looks like, that `DecissionTreeClassifier` tries to treat my problem as multi-label problem and fails when trying to sort labels for second columns (which contains floats).

It there any other way to do this/format the input data, so that `DecisionTreeClassifier` (or any other classifier) would handle it. I can not use two independent classifiers (`DecisionTreeClassifier` and `DecisionTreeRegressor`), because two outputs are related (fantasy books tend to be longer).

Ideally, I would like to use `model.predict_proba()` to get a probability for each category and number of pages for each category. Result should look something like this

```
[[0.9,0.1,0],[100,200,300]]
```

.. meaning 90% probability, that this is a drama book with 100 pages, 10% that this is a fantasy book with 200 pages....

Call stack of the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-c1b30fced85c> in <module>()
      1 model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_leaf=50) # prej smo imeli 5
----> 2 model.fit(data,y_train)
      3 #model.score(data,resitev)

~\AppData\local\AmlWorkbench\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    737             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    738             check_input=check_input,
--> 739             X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
    740         return self
    741 

~\AppData\local\AmlWorkbench\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    144 
    145         if is_classification:
--> 146             check_classification_targets(y)
    147             y = np.copy(y)
    148 

~\AppData\local\AmlWorkbench\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    167     y : array-like
    168     """
--> 169     y_type = type_of_target(y)
    170     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    171             'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:

~\AppData\local\AmlWorkbench\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in type_of_target(y)
    235                          'got %r' % y)
    236 
--> 237     if is_multilabel(y):
    238         return 'multilabel-indicator'
    239 

~\AppData\local\AmlWorkbench\Python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in is_multilabel(y)
    151                  _is_integral_float(np.unique(y.data))))
    152     else:
--> 153         labels = np.unique(y)
    154 
    155         return len(labels) < 3 and (y.dtype.kind in 'biu' or  # bool, int, uint

~\AppData\local\AmlWorkbench\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    208     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    209     if axis is None:
--> 210         return _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    211     if not (-ar.ndim <= axis < ar.ndim):
    212         raise ValueError('Invalid axis kwarg specified for unique')

~\AppData\local\AmlWorkbench\Python\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    275         aux = ar[perm]
    276     else:
--> 277         ar.sort()
    278         aux = ar
    279     flag = np.concatenate(([True], aux[1:] != aux[:-1]))

TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()
```

Comment: Just change those string columns to numbers using LabelEncoder